# I want to limit processes while calling a function in multiprocess how do i do that?

Tags: python

So here is the deal

```
min_range = 1602
max_range = 9999999
for image in range(min_range,max_range):   
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=process,args=image,))
    p1.start()
```

I have these many process to run, i cant run them all at one time it will wreck my system. And i cant run each process at a time using

```
    p1.join()
```

so all i want to do is run 20 processes and wait until they are over once those 20 processes are done run next 20. But i dont know how to achieve that please help me.... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process` is for the case where you want to define/start/control all Processes by yourself.

Your case looks more like a use case for `multiprocessing.Pool`: You define a pool of parallel processes, handle it a function and arguments (a list) and it distributes the work to the processes automatically.

A sidenote: why would you want 20 parallel processes? If you want to do multiprocessing for better using your CPU, the number of parallel processes should be <= number of cores (threads if you have a multi-threaded CPU)